# simplehtmldom parse html save to json

Tags: php, json, simple-html-dom

Here is some html code, how to use simplehtmldom parse html and save to json data?

```
<p>text1</p>
<div>
  <p>text2</p>
<div>
<ul>
  <li>subtext1</li>
  <li>subtext2</li>
</ul>
<p>text3</p>
<div>
  <div>
     <p>text4</p>
  </div>
</div>
<ul>
  <li>subtext1</li>
  <li>subtext2</li>
</ul>
```

I need parse `<ul>` `<li>` `<p>` nod with the original order then save to a json data.

```
[
   {
      "p":"text1"
   },
   {
      "p":"text2"
   },
   {
      "ul":[
         {
            "li":"subtext1"
         },
         {
            "li":"subtext2"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "p":"text3"
   },
   {
      "p":"text4"
   },
   {
      "ul":[
         {
            "li":"subtext3"
         },
         {
            "li":"subtext4"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = str_get_html(YourContentHere);
$data = array();
$count = 0;
foreach($html->find('p') as $li)
{
    $data[$count]['p'] = $li->innertext;
    $count++;
}

foreach($html->find('ul') as $ul)
{
    foreach($ul->find('li') as $li )
    $data[$count]['ul'][]['li'] = $li->innertext;
    $count++;
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

try this, maybe i have mistakes

Comment: thanks, but this will make all the `p` tag in the front of json data, then li in the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
json_encode((array) simplexml_load_string($html_input)
```

Answer (score 0):

solve by myself, Of course I would conplete json_encode() part. for a json tree which I need. thanks.

```
foreach($html->find('p, ul') as $foreach){
    if($foreach->tag =='p'){
        $out .= json_encode($foreach->plaintext);
    }else{
        foreach($foreach->find('li') as $li){
            $out .= json_encode($li->plaintext);
        }
    }
}
```